# Getting last modification date of a schema

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to discover the date a schema was last modified? I'm trying to decide if a schema's still being updated and is therefore "active" in my system.

I use PostgreSQL 9.2 under Linux CentOS release 6.4

Comment: No, not possible.

Comment: Unrelated, but: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). You should really upgrade to a supported version now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Apologies for the question duplication; I did check first, but found nothing similar. I'd *love* to get my server updated, but sluggish sysAdmins... Humph.